# Displaying random image from array in React Native

Tags: arrays, image, react-native, random, display

I am pretty new to React & React Native and I would need some help with displaying random images from an array when pressing a `TouchableOpacity` and calling my function `displayRandomImage()`.

The error I get is

> ReferenceError: Can´t find variable: `imgIndex`

I have tried setting the array index manually to 0 or 1 `source={this.images[0].link}` which works good but I can't figure out why `imgIndex` is not recognized as a random number.

I would be really glad if you could help me with this. Please find the component code below.

```
export default class A extends React.Component {
    constructor () { 
        super();
        this.state = {
            showImageApa: false,
            imgIndex: null,

        };
      }


images = [{link:require('./assets/apa.png')},{link:require('./assets/bil.png')} ];



     displayRandomImage = () => {
      this.setState({
        imgIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
      });

        this.setState({showImageApa: true});

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({showImageApa: false});
          }, 1000);
      };



  render() {
    return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <LinearGradient
            colors={['rgba(25,172,255,0.8)', 'cyan']}
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              height: 800,
            }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.buttonTextTop}>MAX ABC</Text>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTextVersion}>ver 0.2</Text>

          {this.state.showImageApa &&
        <View>
        <Image 
        style={styles.img}
        source={this.images[0].link}/> 
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Apa</Text>

        </View>}

              <TouchableOpacity
                  style={[styles.button]}
                onPress={() => {this.displayRandomImage();}}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>A</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>


    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: react update when state changed, so use this.images[this.state.imgIndex].link

Comment: Tried this and it worked.  I Thought I tried exactly this before but I guess I did something wrong then. However, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you've got only two objects in the *images* array, you can address their locations by referencing images[0] or images[1]. However, when you are using the *Math.floor(Math.random * 3)* function, it returns values [0, 2] and there's no object defined on images[2]. Therefore, the solution would be to change *Math.floor(Math.random * 3)* to **Math.floor(Math.random * 2)** so that the value returned is either 0 or 1 to reference the correct index.

Good luck with your React Native journey!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I realized this mistake now, of course it should be 2. I changed that and added this.images[this.state.imgIndex].link to the onPress event and now it works! Thanks.